# Conditional Joint Function

Tags: conditional-probability, adjoint-functors

Let V,W,Z ~ Poisson(λ) are independent variables and we have:

X = V + W

Y = V + Z

Are Y and X independent under condition V?

I tried to solve this problem with joint distribution but I can't.

Answer (score -1):

> I tried to solve this problem with joint distribution but I can't.

Indeed, that's *not* the way to go.

---

You know that $V,W,$ and $Z$ are **mutually independent** and identically Poisson distributed, and $X=V+W$, $Y=V+Z$.

To demonstrate conditional independence of $X$ and $Y$ given $V$, you must show that: $$\mathsf P(X=x, Y=y\mid V=v) ~~=~~ \mathsf P(X=x\mid V=v)\,\mathsf P(Y=y\mid V=v)$$

Comment: Yes I tried to do that but  I don't know how computing P(X=x,Y=y∣V=v) and others.

Comment: @FATEMEHMOUSAVI Do *not* compute them.  Just substitute $X=V+W$ and $Y=V+Z$.